# How to write junit test for object class in kotlin/android?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, android-junit

Maybe this is very basic question but could not find anything online.

I have created a object class in `kotlin` contains few methods. I am calling those from `ViewModel` and I have written `junit` test case for `ViewModel` where object class instance is mocked, fine so far.

Now, I want to write junit for my object class separately as well even though from `ViewModel` `verify()` calls are working fine.

Some code snippet from my project

```
object InfoHelper {

    fun method(param: Xyz): Boolean {
        return when(param) {
            Result.OK -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you post the actual method under test and the class being passed to it? You've created your own implementation of Result? What is the problem?

Comment: Method definition is not important. What I need is should I create ObjectTest class or just like normal kotlin test class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing Kotlin object classes:

The same as testing a Java static method and class. The class under test and it's methods can be tested directly without initialisation.

Using your class as a loose example..

```
object InfoHelper {
    fun method(param: String): Boolean {
        return when(param) {
            "my string" -> true
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import org.junit.Assert.assertFalse
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
import org.junit.Test

class InfoHelperTest {
    @Test
    fun `some test returns true`() {
        assertTrue(InfoHelper.method("my string"))
    }

    @Test
    fun `some test returns false`() {
        assertFalse(InfoHelper.method("not my string"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe too basic question to ask but just curious to know why it's not ObjectTest instead of ClassTest?